# How do I avoid this osm2pgsql duplicate key error in Windows?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I am attempting to load an OSM .bz2 file into a PostGIS database using osm2pgsql but am stuck at a duplicate key value in the nodes which violates a unique constraint - any suggestions? output is below:

> > C:\Temp>osm2pgsql -s -C 3000 -U postgres -W -d POSTGIS -S C:\temp\default.style
> >     us-west-latest.osm.bz2
> >     osm2pgsql SVN version 0.69-21289M
>
> Password: Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator) Setting up
>   table: planet_osm_point NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not
>   exist, skipping NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist,
>   skipping Setting up table: planet_osm_line NOTICE:  table
>   "planet_osm_line" does not exist, skipping NOTICE:  table
>   "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping Setting up table:
>   planet_osm_polygon NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist,
>   skipping NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist,
>   skipping Setting up table: planet_osm_roads NOTICE:  table
>   "planet_osm_roads" does not exist, skipping NOTICE:  table
>   "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping Mid: pgsql, scale=100,
>   cache=3000MB, maxblocks=384001*8192 Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
>   *** WARNING: intarray contrib module not installed
>   *** The resulting database will not be usable for applying diffs. NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_nodes" does not exist, skipping Setting up
>   table: planet_osm_ways NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_ways" does not
>   exist, skipping Setting up table: planet_osm_rels NOTICE:  table
>   "planet_osm_rels" does not exist, skipping
>
> !! You are running this on 32bit system, so at most !! 3GB of RAM can
>   be used. If you encounter unexpected !! exceptions during import, you
>   should try running in slim !! mode using parameter -s.
>
> Reading in file: us-west-latest.osm.bz2 Processing: Node(113650k)
>   Way(0k) Relation(0k)COPY_END for COPY planet_osm_nodes  FROM STDIN; 
>   failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "planet_osm_node s_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2147483647) already
>   exists. CONTEXT:  COPY planet_osm_nodes, line 98676608
>
> Error occurred, cleaning up

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using osm2pgsql version 0.69 which does [not support 64-bit identifiers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/64-bit_Identifiers#General_OSM_processing) and will accordingly not handle OSM files more recent than February 2013.

Although unrelated to the error you're getting you should make sure you are using a 64-bit system to make use of all your RAM and use a .osm.pbf extract, not a .osm.bz2 one.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I had used the HOTOSM package and apparently it switched to an older osm2pgsql executable, I copied/replaced the latest one (64-bit) into the HOTOSM \bin folder and it works great.